# Using Reachability to check for connection before method is run

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, reachability, appdelegate

I would like to use [Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) to check for an Internet connection in my application.

I have found [a tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-detecting-network-changes-with-reachability/) which walks through setting this up in the application. In the tutorial it explains about 'Step 4' - a Reachability Manager. It mentions the following:

> This is useful if an object needs direct access to the reachability
>   instance that the singleton object manages.

What would be an example of this? What object would need direct access to the instance?

Within my application I have multiple methods which require an internet connection to be run. What I am trying to achieve is one of two approaches:

1. Show a UIAlertView when the internet connection is lost asking the
   user to retry.

   Note: This is only on certain view controllers and not through out
   the application as I do not need to completely restrict access
   through out.
2. OR - I would like to use a method to check an internet connection
   exists before running the actual method that requires the
   connection.

How can I set this up using Reachability in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 4th sections there's an example of wrapper for Reachability (but in that realization there's no kReachabilityChangedNotification handling). So how should you use it? — 
As you can see in interface of MTReachabilityManager, there're 1 method for getting singleton instance of manager and 4 methods for working with it:

```
+ (BOOL)isReachable;
+ (BOOL)isUnreachable;
+ (BOOL)isReachableViaWWAN;
+ (BOOL)isReachableViaWiFi;
```

For your second approach in method that want connection You have to do something like:

```
if ([[MTReachabilityManager sharedManager] isReachable]) {
     //do internet
} else {
     //alert 'no internet' or something
}
```

For first approach (connection was lost during getting data from network) this wrapper would not help you (not implemented listening of kReachabilityChangedNotification). So you have to add code from section 3 (Step 3: Notifications) of this tutorial — add listener for kReachabilityChangedNotification somewhere before call network code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityDidChange:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
```

and add method to handle notifications (will be fired when internet changed it's state):

```
- (void)reachabilityDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    Reachability *reachability = (Reachability *)[notification object];
    if ([reachability isReachable]) {
        NSLog(@"Reachable");
        //if before there was no internet - now you can do whatever user wants when there was no internet
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Unreachable");
        //alert retry
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, In the first example in question. If I wanted to only check for internet connection on specific view controllers how would I handle this. So on a specific view controller I would like to show an alert that they could not get passed until an internet connection is returned, but not all view controllers just one as an example?

Comment: Would I only add the observer to the view controller viewDidLoad, for the view controller I would like to monitor this?

Comment: 1)Yes, you have to check connection ([[MTReachabilityManager sharedManager] isReachable]) just before you want to load something (wrap you network code with 'if').

Comment: 2)Yes) You can add observer in controller you want) viewDidLoad is a good place for it, the only thing - do not forget to unsubscribe from observing (is dealloc or somewhere)

Comment: if You want to add observer for all controller - You can create either category for UIViewController or create base view controller class for all you vc that need network working. Also is a good practice to create some network manager, that will handle all network working (also network availability) -- i recommend You to see at direction of AFNetworking, it's really good)

Comment: I currently use AFNetworking for internet resource loading yes, is that what you are referring to (in terms of network manager)?

Comment: If You are using AFNetworking 2.0, there's class AFNetworkReachabilityManager and all base network classes have link to it @property (readonly, nonatomic, strong) AFNetworkReachabilityManager *reachabilityManager;  https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#network-reachability-manager

Comment: If You are using 1.x in AFHTTPClient there's @property (readonly, nonatomic, assign) AFNetworkReachabilityStatus networkReachabilityStatus; you can just use them

Comment: in 1.x you also can use - (void)setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:(void ( ^ ) ( AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status ))block and set to block what ever you want (if internet became active- start doing something, other way show alert, or something)

Comment: I am using 1.2.1 for AFNetworking. Should I look to update this to 2.0 is this a stable cocoapod release for this? If I use AFNetworkingReachabilityManager would I not need to include the Reachability pod - can I complete the same checks using this new AFNetworkingReachabilityManager for the connection - can you update your question to show how to use this different approach with AFNM please?